# Rails 4 Migrations from MySQL Tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, migration, rails-migrations

I have a pre seeded database for Countries/Regions/Cities. Is it possible to generate the migration file automatically for these tables?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cities` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `region_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Latitude` float NOT NULL,
  `Longitude` float NOT NULL,
  `TimeZone` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `DmaId` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `County` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Code` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=42965 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `countries` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `FIPS104` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `ISO2` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `ISO3` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `ISON` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `Internet` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `Capital` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MapReference` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NationalitySingular` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NationalityPlural` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Currency` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CurrencyCode` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Population` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Comment` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=276 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `regions` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Code` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `ADM1Code` char(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5400 ;
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your asking, why do you need migrations if these tables are already seeded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
rake db:schema:dump
```

Comment: does that create the migration files ?

Comment: It will create a `schema.rb` file which you can break up into migrations.

Comment: any link i see on how i can do that? is there a way also to save the seed data into the seed file?

Comment: What's wrong with sql dump of data? You can then load it in seed file (and I can't believe you have 3 times more points than me and you really ask those questions when they are easily googleable)

Comment: new to rails (from PHP we handle much differently). i tried a couple of seed gems but it seems to not dump the content into the seed.rb